# How do I add a jquery plugin to rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to use LiveFilter https://github.com/mikemerritt/LiveFilter in my rails app.  It does exactly what I want to do - filter existing elements using a search box.

How would I go about adding this (or any other) jquery plugin to rails 3.1, so that it works with the asset pipeline?  If you know, will it be different in 3.2?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add the `livefilter.js` file to `your app/assets/javascripts` directory, and add a require directive to your JS manifest(s) (e.g. `application.js`) :

```
//= require livefilter
```

AFAIK, the asset pipeline works the same in 3.1 and 3.2.

Comment: A better place to have the plugins is in `vendor/assets/javascripts`, and require as usual in your application.js file

Comment: @Edward as Terw added, you can add your assets to three different locations. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization for more.

Comment: Thanks that's great.  I've put it in `vendor/assets/javascripts` as Terw suggested